# How to display the field of the parent object

Tags: javascript

```
const human = {
    name: "asdasd",
    mouth: {
        sayName(){
            console.log(this.name)
        }
    }
}

human.mouth.sayName()
// undefined
```

HELLO!
I need the name field to be taken from the parent object
THANK YOU!

Comment: It cannot be done this way because there's no connection between the objects. Try editing the question and explain what is the problem you're trying to solve - you may discover new solutions beside the one that doesn't work.

Comment: change `this` to `human`, but i don't know if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```js
const human = {
  name: "asdasd",
  mouth: {
    sayName() {
      return human.name;
    }
  }
};
console.log(human.mouth.sayName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that 'this' will refer the immediate object, since in the code `this.name` will refer to the `name' property of the mouth object(which is not defined).
You will have to directly refer to the object whose name you want to mention ie

```
  const human = {
  name: "asdasd",
  mouth: {
    sayName() {
      return human.name;
    }
  }
};
console.log(human.mouth.sayName());
```